# Submitting only part of a page in ADF Faces?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

How do I submit only part of a page in ADF Faces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ADF Faces af:subForm component represents an independently submittable region of a page. When used within an af:form tag or within an JSF HTML h:form tag, af:subForm lets you control which components should be validated and pushed into the model without having to use multiple forms on a page.

Comment: Cool, you answered your own question within a minute. But what's your actual purpose? Is it just a test topic or so?

Comment: @BalusC - some folk post questions about things they had to figure out so in future others will find them in a Google search (part of the "blog/wiki" aspect of the site).

Comment: Exactly right-- I have a list of lessons learned from my using ADF Faces and thought I'd share with others.

Comment: Ah yes. You however yet has to accept the answer, else this unanswered question will be poked up by community at times. Or would you like to have more input/answers?